# How to create background event as every minute in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

i want to make a background service like,if user open the app and close after every minute one action view will be display that view would play video that video also from server side.how it s possible?

Comment: what??? It is not clear what you are asking here. Very confuse.

Comment: Actually,i wanna background notification like a alarm notification

Comment: could u say how to play video in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application,..state?

Comment: NSDate *alarmTime=[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5.0];
    UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    if(notifyAlarm){
        notifyAlarm.fireDate=alarmTime;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval=10;
        notifyAlarm.soundName=@"";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody=@"i m new in this concepts";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }

Comment: Above code every 5 second send notification same way i want to replace the view like want to play video

Comment: After reading your comment, it think you should read some very basic of iOS before just coding every thing. you need to understand the basic behavior of iOS.

Comment: ohh thats ok!!!,.....u could say is it possible to display video when apps gone background state..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by 3 days

1. Local Notification - By this a local notification will appear and this  would appear if app is terminated,in background, or active. A Banner would arrive and if you click it you can decide what action will be done in your appdelegate - This requires user interactability to work.
2. Push Notification - Same as above but the notification comes from server.
3. NSTimer - only works as the class its in is in memory.

Create an NSTimer object as an instance variable, as well as an integer to count the counter.

```
 @implementation myClass {
NSTimer *myTimer, int counter;
}

-viewDidLoad{
counter = 61;
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)checkTimer{
if(counter <=1){
    counter = 61;
}
else {
    counter --;
    //do your video playing work here
 }
}
```

Comment: is it possible if i close my app,is that video will popup?

Comment: No, video wont pop up, but a notification or banner will come, if user interacts with that banner then u can decide the action as to what will happen but as by this time app is active so the code has to be deployed in app delegate. this only works for push/local notifications

Comment: is there any other way to display video?

Comment: then how the alarm comes,while set the alarm after some time it will popup same way is it popup video in iOS?

Comment: there is no way to play a video while the application is terminated or in background as per my knowledge

Comment: is it possible every minute will launch app in iOS without user click the app?

Answer (score 0):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

```
NSCalendar *gregCalendar12 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent12 = [gregCalendar12 components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:[NSDate date]];


[dateComponent12 setWeekday:7];
[dateComponent12 setHour:14];
[dateComponent12 setMinute:46];

UILocalNotification *notification12 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification12 setAlertBody:@"u got message!"];
[notification12 setFireDate:[gregCalendar12 dateFromComponents:dateComponent12]];
notification12.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
notification12.applicationIconBadgeNumber+=1;
[notification12 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification12];
```